# List Table(s) of Series Here

Tags: sequences-and-series, big-list

I've been interested in series expansions of all types of mathematical functions.  I was wondering if anyone has ever created a large list of all types of series.  For example, [Wolfram's Mathworld's Maclauren Series page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) list a bunch of those series.  [Herbert S. Wilf's Generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) lists some power series at the end of section 2.5.  Wikipedia lists some generalizations of series [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)) and some Taylor series [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

I was wondering if there is a giant, somewhat comprehensive list of series somewhere.  I'm especially interested in basic mathematical constants and elementary functions, but I'd like to have access to as many different series as possible.  Could someone help me find some links or books with series?

Sorry if this seems hopelessly vague, but I would really like to have access to tons of series.

Comment: What do you want the series for? Anybody can come up with any crazy composition of functions, and that gives rise to a new series.

Comment: I'm really looking for series for elementary costants and functions to try to come up with new formulations and possibly closed forms of certain functions.  For example, I'm studying the series $x+x^2+x^4+x^8+\dots+x^{2^n}+\dots$.  I'm wondering if it's possible to find a closed form for the generating function.  Mainly, I'd like to see various series for elementary functions and constants.  I guess that currently I'm looking for series involving $e$, exponential series, and logarithm series.

Comment: That series defines a [lacunary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function), it is even the first example given there.

Comment: @MattGroff: This seem like a [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) type post. Would you like me to convert it to CW?

Comment: @robjohn: Yes, if you don't mind.  That would be excellent!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

L B W Jolley, Summation of Series. Dover edition, published in 1961, is a revised and enlarged version of the 1925 original. "Over $1100$ common series are here collected, summed, and grouped for easy reference."

Answer (score 2):

There's a huge list (with summations near the bottom) of infinite series (although mostly infinite products [here](http://pi.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html).